# Who introduced the notation $x^2$?

Tags: notation, math-history, exponentiation

In the book 'Problem Solving and Number Theory' I read

> The  law  of  quadratic  reciprocity  was  discovered  for  the ﬁrst
>   time, in a complex form, by L. Euler who published it in his paper
>   entitled “Novae demonstrationes circa divisores numerorum formae $xx + nyy$ .”

When and who introduced the notation $x^2$ ? What is the name for this notation? ( Not scientific, is it? )

Comment: See [Earliest known use of symbols of mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/operation.html) in the "Operations" page, under "Exponents". First use of modern notation for positive integers seems to date back to Descartes's *Geometry*, *except* for squares. For negative integers and fractions, Newton. I believe it is called "exponential notation".

Comment: You should check the book by FLorian Cajori about the history of notations. It has a whole chapter on the history of exponents!

Comment: "And... Descartes tended not to use 2 as an exponent, however, usually writing $aa$ rather than $a^2$, perhaps because $aa$ occupies no less space than $a^2$." - That's it, then. ( If you create an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you ).

Comment: Cajori's book [is available on archive.org](http://www.archive.org/details/historyofmathema031756mbp), the relevant section on exponents [starts here](http://www.archive.org/stream/historyofmathema031756mbp#page/n353/mode/2up).

Comment: Just had a quick browse on Google ebooks. The book by Florian Cajori ( two volumes actually ) is a gem! - Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: And found it on Archive.org thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited to https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this page](http://jeff560.tripod.com/operation.html) the earliest known use of integers to represent repeated multiplication is by Nicole Oresme in the mid 1300s. However, he didn't use a raised integer notation. The rest of this answer is taken from that page.

Nicolas Chuquet used raised integers in 1484, though for him $12^3$ was a shorthand for $12x^3$.

In 1636 James Hume used roman numerals as exponents, e.g. for $12^3$ he would have written $12^\textrm{iii}$, but apart from that minor distinction he was essentially using modern notation.

Rene Descartes used raised arabic numericals as exponents in 1637, with the exception that he tended to write $xx$ rather than $x^2$, though he would still write $x^3$, $x^4$ etc. He wrote:

> ...$aa$ ou $a^2$ pour multiplier à par soiméme; et $a^3$ pour le multiplier encore une fois par $a$, et ainsi à l'infini.

which roughly translates as

> ...$aa$ or $a^2$ to multiply by itself, and $a^3$ to multiply again by $a$, and so ad infinitum.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know specifically who, but I recall that the notion was already invented during Euler's time.

It was just conventional to write $xx$ instead of $x^2$, i.e. one would write $x, xx, x^3, x^4, \ldots$.
This is probably similar to why we write $f',f'', f^{(3)}, f^{(4)}, \ldots$ for the notation of a derivative.

Comment: So in Euler's time it was convention to write $xx$ instead of $x^2$ ?

Comment: Using $xx$ lasted for a long time. Even as late as Riemann's "*Über die Anzahl der Primzahlen unter einen gegebenen Grösse*" [[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Number_of_Primes_Less_Than_a_Given_Magnitude)].

Answer (score 7):

In their modern form, exponents were introduced by Descartes in the early $1630$s, at the same time as $x$.  There are numerous precursor forms of the exponent.

Although Descartes used the notation $x^n$ for $n \ge 3$, he ordinarily used $xx$ instead of our $x^2$. The notation of Descartes was fairly quickly widely adopted, with England as usual being more cautious.  The form $x^2$ was used by some people, the form $xx$ by others. Euler used both.  I believe he used $x^2$ far more often than $xx$. Maybe he thought $xx$ looked nice in a title.