# What operations have represented 2^2?

Tags: exponentiation, math-history

I knew [image: equation]= 2.2 and 2.2= 2+2
What operations have represented 2^2?

? = [image: 2^2]

3+3+3=9 ; 3.3.3=81 and continue is [image: equation].
 what is representation for operations [image: equation] ? I assume to have a operation, it is called f. I have 3f3=[image: equation] ; [image: 3^{3^3}]=3.3.3 ; 3.3= 3+3+3; what is representation for operations f ?

Comment: $3^2 - 5{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Maybe the link to this question can help you?
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76156/who-introduced-the-notation-x2?rq=1

Comment: You need to learn to format your posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: May be it's the [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) operation? Seems to me like the person is asking for $\text{plus}(\text{plus}(3,3),3)$ being multiplication, $\text{multiplication}(\text{multiplication}(3,3),3)$ being exponentiation and then moves on to asking what $\text{exponentiation}(\text{exponentiation}(3,3),3)$ is called.

Comment: Refer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849528/what-is-this-operator-called/1849531#1849531)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understand your question. The expression `2^2` is the same as $2^2$ and itmeans multiplying $2$ by itself $2$ times. So
$$
2^2 = 2\cdot 2 = 4.
$$
Now it happens that $2$ plus $2$ is also equal to $4$. It is not true in general that $n^m = n + m$. For example $3^2 = 3\cdot 3 = 9$ and $3 + 3 = 6$.

Comment: Yes i want to ask if 3+3+3=9 ; 3.3.3=81 and continue is 3^3^3. what is representation for operations 3^3^3 ? I assume to have a operation, it is called f. I have 3f3=3^3^3 ; 3^3=3.3.3 ; 3.3= 3+3+3; what is representation for operations f ?

Comment: @QChíNguyễn Tetration.